# Evitar que los elementos de una vista se escondan al llamar a viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: swift, swift2

He estado siguiendo un tutorial de como implementar un login con parse con función de loguearse con Facebook y Twitter, sin embargo, me encuentro con un detalle.

En principio los elementos de la vista principal se esconden por medio de  la función `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, es decir, se envían hacia la parte inferior de la pantalla y posteriormente se desplazan hacia arriba en forma de animación, esta animación se ejecuta en la función `viewDidAppear`.

Hasta ahi todo es perfecto, sin embargo cuando selecciono alguno de los `textFields` que forman parte de la vista para introducir un texto, como es obvio el teclado aparece y en teoría debería desplazar los elementos hacia arriba para no ocultarlos cuando se escribe, aquí supongo que se vuelve a activar la función `viewDidLayoutSubviews` y ejecuta el fragmento de código que me esconde todos los elementos en la parte inferior tal como se realiza cuando se carga la aplicación para hacer posible la animación.

¿Cómo puedo evitar que los elementos desaparezcan cada vez que intente escribir en alguno de los `textFields`?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

 // create an array of all the views we want to animate in when we launch the screen

        viewsToAnimate = [self.logInView?.usernameField, self.logInView?.passwordField, self.logInView?.logInButton, self.logInView?.passwordForgottenButton, self.logInView?.facebookButton, self.logInView?.signUpButton, self.logInView?.logo]
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()


        // We to position all the views off the bottom of the screen
        // and then make them rise back to where they should be
        // so we track their final position in an array
        // but change their frame so they are shifted downwards off the screen


        viewsFinalYPosition = [CGFloat]();
        for viewToAnimate in viewsToAnimate {
            //print(viewToAnimate.frame)
            let currentFrame = viewToAnimate.frame
            print(viewsFinalYPosition.count)
            viewsFinalYPosition.append(currentFrame.origin.y)
            viewToAnimate.frame = CGRectMake(currentFrame.origin.x, self.view.frame.height + currentFrame.origin.y, currentFrame.width, currentFrame.height)
        }
    }

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {


        super.viewDidAppear(animated)


        // Now we'll animate all our views back into view
        // and, using the final position we stored, we'll
        // reset them to where they should be
        if viewsFinalYPosition.count == self.viewsToAnimate.count {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut,  animations: { () -> Void in
                for viewToAnimate in self.viewsToAnimate {
                    print(viewToAnimate.frame)
                    let currentFrame = viewToAnimate.frame
                     print(self.viewsFinalYPosition.count)
                    viewToAnimate.frame = CGRectMake(currentFrame.origin.x, self.viewsFinalYPosition.removeAtIndex(0), currentFrame.width, currentFrame.height)
                }
                }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

[ViewsDissapear](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4915071/viewsDissapear.mov)

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4915071/viewsDissapear.mov

Comment: Estas seguro que todas las conexiones estan correcta? Entre los textfields y las variables?

Comment: Si que lo estan o deberian. He seguido este tutorial y la verdad es que me va perfecto ha no ser por el detalle que he explicado arriba. çhttps://www.codementor.io/swift/tutorial/customize-parse-twitter-facebook-signup-login-view-animations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asígnales la posición inicial (escondido) en el `viewDidLoad` o añade una propiedad booleana:

```
var initialPositionSet = false
```

De manera que en el `viewDidLayoutSubviews` la pongas a `true` cuando ya se hayan escondido los elementos:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if !self.initialPositionSet {
        self.initialPositionSet = true

        // establecer posición inicial
    }
}
```

Creo que algo así te puede funcionar.

Comment: Lo primero de poner el fragmento de codigo en ViewDidAppear ya lo habia ejecutado y simplemente no va, lo que hace es que me manda todos los elementos en la parte superior sobreencimados. Y lo de condicionar la ejecucion del codigo me parecio una buena idea sin embargo es como si nunca reposicionara los elementos. He puesto breakpoints y ejecuta el codigo pero no pasa nada.

Comment: Ha funcionado!!. El problema era que el fragmento de codigo que reposicionaba los elementos se ejecutaba dos veces por eso no funcionaba condicionandolo con un bool, por lo que use un contador. Gracias,

Comment: Me alegro de que te sirviera de ayuda